# Order by for a method in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to show the top 10 of clients with balance from bigger to smaller. but the prob is that balance is method.

```
class ClientsBalance(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Client')

    def inputs(self):
        total = self.client.invoice_set.aggregate(sum=Sum('total_general'))
        return round(total[("sum")] or 0, 2)

    def outputs(self):
        total = self.client.clientpayment_set.aggregate(sum=Sum('total_paid'))
        return round(total[("sum")] or 0, 2)

    def balance(self):
        return self.outputs() - self.inputs()

def Dashboard(request):
    clientsbalances = clientsbalance_set.all()[:10]
    context = {'clientsbalances': clientsbalances}

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting and sorting is a database operation.  But model methods are only available to python.

You will want to create a custom Manager (or a QuerySet, used as a manager) which annotates balance.  Then you'll be able to sort by it.

Comment: can you help me with this example pls